# Is it possible to use "run command" within a node js Azure Function?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have a Powershell Script on a Windows VM and can it run from outside of the VM via "run command" function.

Is it possible to use this also from a NodeJS Azure Function?

Do i have to configure dependencies and just do not find where I can configure?

For example I want to run this command from the NodeJS Azure Function:

```
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name win-vm -g my-resource-group \
    --scripts @script.ps1 --parameters "arg1=somefoo" "arg2=somebar"
```

Answer (score 0):

- There is an option while creating the function apps. We need to choose either PowerShell or any kind of programming language `NodeJS & Powershell`. For an instance check with PowerShell as required. And create a function app.

[image]

[image]

- The second option here is to execute a query in the `node JS` where we can run the command. To execute the command and test, check the screens below.

[image]

[image]

Thanks @msp4msps for the clear steps
Refer [**Running PowerShell in Azure function**](https://tminus365.com/running-powershell-in-azure-functions/) for more details